# Validation messages not coming in the form displayed through editorfor template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a simple MVC3 application in which I am using editorfor template to display a simple form containing two fields and these properties are having model-level validation having "Required" attribute.
But when I click the submit button on form and check the ModelState in the controller action, it comes as Invalid but the error messages are not displaying in the form.

I am pasting the code below:

1) Models:

```
public class EmployeeList
{
    public List<Employee> ListOfEmployees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="{0} is required.")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="{0} is required.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

2) Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddEmployee(EmployeeList ListOfEmployees1)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            service.AddEmployee(ListOfEmployees1);
            return RedirectToAction("ListofEmployees");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

3) Main View (AddEmployee.cshtml):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddEmployee", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "testForm" }))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ListOfEmployees)
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </p>
}
```

EditorFor template View (Employee.cshtml):

```
@model test.Models.Employee
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I use a partial view instead of editorfor template to display those two fields, than the validation messages comes on the form but the same is not happening with editorfor template.
Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action method, return the view with the model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddEmployee(EmployeeList ListOfEmployees1)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ....
  }
  return View(ListOfEmployees1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ques it does not work because you use EditorFor for a model of collection type. Instead try something like:

```
@for(var i=0; i< Model.ListOfEmployees.Count; i++){
   Html.EditorFor(m => m.ListOfEmployees[i])
}
```

Comment: No, this is incorrect. `EditorFor()` will render a collection correctly. In fact this will solution will break since the controls `name` attributes will not match the indexed property names and the model would be null on post back.